# Calling a method from different class

Tags: java

Hi so I'm still learning to use methods, but one of my assignments requires me to call a method from a method in a different .java file.

The problem is "Sets" is not recognized and it displays an error message stating that both "Sets" cannot be resolved to a variable. Am I calling the method incorrectly?

This is the method if it is relevant. It comes from a java file called Sets.

```
public static final int Initial_Pop =
        (int)(EARTH_AT * EARTH_BT * 0.4);
```

This is the method I'm trying to call the above method..

```
public static void plusPeople (int[][] earth, int newPerson) {

    int [][] earthpopulation = new int [Sets.EARTH_AT][Sets.EARTH_BT];
}
```

I apologize if I'm unclear or did not provide enough information. If so please tell me!

Comment: Each `.java` file should have a `package` declaration at the very top. Are your two classes in the same package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access EARTH_AT and EARTH_BT and I don't know if these are static. Even though the variable declared is INITIAL_ALIVE_COUNT.

Also remember to check if both classes are in the same Folder (or package). If not, you'll have to import the Sets class.

Comment: I feel silly. I can't believe my classes were not in the same package. I wish I could upvote everyone here :(

Answer (score 0):

when you call `Sets.EARTH_AT` and `Sets.EARTH_BT`, these are not methods, but rather variables within the Sets class. Make sure these are static variables inside Sets class